# how I can hide displaying result of exec command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
WHILE @nxt < @rc
    BEGIN 
       set @sql = (select Rec from DmsRec where row=@nxt)
       use TestDB1
       exec (@sql)
       select @rc_child = @@ROWCOUNT
       use MyTempDB
       if @rc_child = 0
       begin
            insert into DMSResults 
            select DOCID from DmsRec where row=@nxt
       end
       set @nxt = @nxt + 1
    END
```

My Question is **how I can hide displaying result of exec command.**
(using Sql Server 2008r2) Above query is small part of complete procedure.

Accessing multiple conditions,value and multiple databases I generate a select statement and stored in *Rec Field* into table DmsRec

After generating require Select.... statement I stored it into table DmsRec.
e.g. `SELECT ACCD FROM M_TABLE WHERE 1=1  and ACCD='0034422'`.

This select statement which is stored as a value in table DmsRec
want to execute in different database.

So I used `use` command and change the database name, access the recordset.
If the executed sql *(return 0 row)* then run the `insert` command which is executed in different database.
With this I came to know wether Inserted *docid* into *DMSResults* is those tranaction whose master is not avalialbel.

It works perfectly but can not hide displaying records of exec command.

I run `exec(@sql)` is only to check whether it is returning any row or not.
and stored rowcount value into variable.

But do not want to display records in grid (at the same time result {effected rows} should stored in variable).

Without changing options in SSMS manually i.e.
Tools/Options, Query Results/SQL Server/Results to XX, check "Discard results after query executes"

Comment: Set nocount off

Comment: No Sir, that I already given....but exec(@sql) displaying records in Result Pan Grid.  I want to display message only e.g. ( 1 row(s) affected) but not result.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - based on comments below

You can use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) and pass parameters to it, even OUTPUT parameters.

Here's an example - you will need to amend the SQL query you're storing slightly

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @Rows INT, @nxt INT = 1
CREATE TABLE DmsRec (row INT, rec NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO DmsRec(row, rec)
    VALUES(1, 1)

SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS ( SELECT rec FROM dbo.DmsRec WHERE row = @nxt) SET @Rows = 1  ELSE SET @Rows = 0' --+'; SELECT @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@nxt INT, @Rows INT OUTPUT', @nxt, @Rows OUTPUT;
SELECT @Rows
```

[image]

```
SET @nxt = 0 -- record doesn't exist
SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS ( SELECT rec FROM dbo.DmsRec WHERE row = @nxt) SET @Rows = 1 ELSE SET @Rows = 0' 

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@nxt INT, @Rows INT OUTPUT', @nxt, @Rows OUTPUT;
SELECT @Rows
```

[image]

You can then use @Rows variable to determine whether you need to insert a new record or not.

```
If @Rows = 1
BEGIN
   --INSERT record
END
```

Comment: Pls. read in main post. field *Rec' having value like 'INDIA', 'UK', 'US' there is sql query text stored (see in the post). And every row is different sql (it may different columns also). Thus I can not use simply Declare @rows table (rec INT) it gives an error 'Column name ....does not match'

Comment: And is all you're checking for ,after each execution, is whether the row doesn't exist and if so insert a new record, yes?

Comment: YES!, also note checking is in different database and inserting value in table DmsResult is in different database.